# How to reduce space between equations and graphics

Tags: graphics, equations

I am using this simple example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pgfbaselayers}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\graphicspath{{images/}}


\begin{document}
 \begin{gather*} 
\ce{S + E -> SE \\ 
SE -> S + E \\
SE -> P + E
 }
\end{gather*}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[clip, trim=0.6 1.75 5 1, width=50mm,scale=0.5]{C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/PosterGraphics/MMplot1.pdf}
  \caption{A plot of a single realisation of all the species for the Michaelis-Meten model}
  \label{fig:boat1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

And I want to reduce the distance between my graph, and the chemical equations as currently it is too large. I've read other threads on TexSE, but they're all to do with distance between caption and graphic, which is not an issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add the image to `gather*`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{gather*}
\ce{S + E -> SE \\
SE -> S + E \\
SE -> P + E
 }
\\
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image}
\end{gather*}

\caption{A plot of a single realisation of all
  the species for the Michaelis-Meten model}\label{fig:boat1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, I'd let it float (no `H` option, but `htp`).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the figure where you want and not where LaTeX considers, don't use a floating figure, use a captioned graphic. This can be done with `\captionof` command from `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}


\begin{document}
 \begin{gather*} 
\ce{S + E -> SE \\ 
SE -> S + E \\
SE -> P + E
 }
\end{gather*}
{\par
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{A plot of a single realisation of all the species for the Michaelis-Meten model\label{fig:boat1}}
\par}

As can be seen in figure~\ref{fig:boat1}\dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put `\setlength{\intextsep}{-50pt}` in your preamble and choose instead `-50pt` your desired number

Answer (score 0):

off-topic:

- do you really need all packages loaded in preamble?
- some of them are loaded twice even three times ... (in mwe below indicated with `%%` and `%%%`)

on-topic:

- write your chem equation outside of math environment
- after chem reaction add `\vskip-\baselineskip`

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{tasks}
%%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{float}
%%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
%\usepackage{pgfbaselayers}
%\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
%\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
%\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
%%%\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%%\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{center}
\ce{S + E -> SE  \\
    SE -> S + E  \\
    SE -> P + E}
    \end{center}\vskip-\baselineskip % <--
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[clip, trim=0.6 1.75 5 1,
                 width=50mm]{C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/PosterGraphics/MMplot1.pdf}
  \caption{A plot of a single realisation of all the species for the Michaelis-Meten model}
  \label{fig:boat1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know a lot of the packages are excessive, but this is for a poster I'm doing. So a lot of those are applicable to the poster

Comment: but it is sufficient to load each only ones ... :-).  for your problem and mwe all commented in my answer are superfluous.

Comment: Sorry to be a bug, but would this method carry over if I was putting it in a poster. Ie This was inside a box on latex

Comment: sorry, but i don't understood you. in your question is not mentioned poster ... please edit your question and clarify, what is the problem. in poster is better not use `figures` environments, see @Ignasi answer.